# Stream Log Analytics Heartbeat Metrics to Event Hub

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub, azure-log-analytics

Our Edge Devices provide regular Heartbeats which are available as Heartbeat records in Log Analytics in Azure (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/solution-agenthealth).

We can query those metrics in the Log Analytics Workspace and get a heartbeat timestamp per computer.

However we need to have this information available also in our Backend application.

I don't think it's a good idea to use log analytics like a database and query it directly from our backend, so there should be a way to transfer this information to a place where we can easily query it.

Is there any way to forward those Heartbeat metrics to an Azure Function (probably via Event Hub) where we could store them for access from our Backend application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Log Analytics, there is no way to forward those metrics to an Azure function or Eventhub. You should use query to fetch those data.

Maybe you should check in the Edge Devices side, if those metrics can be sent directly to eventhub.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah, that's the way i implemented it right now. I send a periodic heartbeat message from an edge module via the IoT Hub Upstream.